# How to find visible part of prism

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

I have:

- point A (x,y,z) as a "view point"
- point A2 (x,y,z) as center of quadrangular prism
- prism size (width, length, height)

So it's something like this (clickable) 
[image: Example]

Imagine that you are standing at point A and looking at our prism. I need to get a quad, representating part that is visible from point A. In my example (img) it will be quad from points FBDH. I was thinking about some kind of projection to the plane perpendicular to line connecting point A and center of my prism, but i am not very good at geometry so i need help.

My question is: how can i get the coordinates of this quad using my source data (coordinates of "view point", center and sizes of prism).

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** *Point A can have any coordinates, higher of lower it doesn't matter. Prism is also could be rotated around every axis.*

Comment: I can't tell from the picture how high up $A$ really is. But is it good enough to find the vertices you can see? And what kind of answer do you want? Pseudocode?

Comment: Point A can have any coordinates, higher of lower it doesn't matter. Prism is also could be rotated around every axis. Pseudocode is the best option, yes. But i will appresiate any formulas and advices also)

Comment: @Arthur if we find the vertices we can see it will mean that we will have some extra vertices, i guess. I mean, in my example we see 6 of them, but i need only 4 to make a quad, i don't need the closest two

Comment: Unless you restrict where your view point can be, the “shadow” of the cube will in general be a hexagon, not a quadrilateral. Imagine, for example, that you’re sighting along one of the long diagonals of the cube.

Comment: What type of projection are you using? Perspective, orthogonal, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a face, you see all the four points on it.

Compute the centers $C_k$ of all the faces, and the outer normal to that face $\bf n_k$.
Compute the vectors $\bf{v_k} = \vec {AC_k}$.  Only the faces for which $\bf {v_k} \cdot \bf{n_k} <0$ will be visible.

In another way, associate to each vertex $P_k$, the normals $\bf n_{k,j}$ corresponding to each of the three concurrent faces.
The visible points will be those for which at least one of the dot products $\vec {AP_k} \cdot \bf n_{k,j }$ is negative.
In this way you also can arrange the points as having $3,2,1,0$ negative dot products, and those with $0$ will be the obscured points.